# Program to make a file clean itself

Tags: python

I have the following program:

```
fhandle=open(filename,'r')
fhandle2=open(filename2,'w')
data=fhandle.read()
data=data.replace('{',"    ")
data=data.replace('}',"    ")
fhandle2.write(data)
```

This gets the job done, removing the '{}' from a string, however it involves 2 files. How can I make it so the first file cleans itself without the need for a second file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open(filename, 'r+') as file:
    data=file.read()
    data=data.replace('{',"    ")
    data=data.replace('}',"    ")
    file.write(data)
```

That should do the trick. Using file mode r+ allows you to read and write to the same file without having to open up 2 separate files.

Comment: Thank you, your answer gets the job done but it places the fixed text underneath the old text. I end up having two texts simultaneously. Is there a way I can bypass this?

Comment: `file.seek(0)` just before you `file.write(data)`.  It'll reset the cursor back to the start of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are loading the file into memory and not running into issues, you should be find truncating the first open file and just writing to it:

```
file.seek(0) #navigates to the beginning of the file
file.truncate() #deletes the contents
```

From here you can write to it as you would any other file. This file should be opened in read and write. (r+)

Comment: The mode needs to be r+.  w+ will destroy the original contents.